# Can annotations be used to narrow types in Python

Tags: python, types, mypy

I think in reality I'm going to use a different design, where `_attrib` is set in the construct and can therefore not be `None`, however I'm fascinated to see if there's a way to make MyPy happy with this approach. I have a situation where an attribute (in this instance `_attrib`) is set after the construction of the `Thing` and there are a number of methods which require it to be set. It seamed reasonable, therefore, to spin up a teeny decorator to validate if the `_attrib` was set and to chuck an exception if it's not. The below code, however, causes MyPy to still complain - although the error is `Item "None" of "Optional[Any]" has no attribute "upper"`, so I think the type of `self` is getting completely lost. I'm also getting `Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[Any, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]", expected "F")` on `return inner`.

```py
class AttribIsNone(Exception):
    ...

F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[...,Any]
def guard(func: F) -> F:
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._attrib is None:
            raise AttribIsNoneException()
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class Thing:
    _attrib: str | None

    @guard
    def guarded_function(self) -> str:
        return self._attrib.upper()
```

Ideally I think I'd bind `F` to something like `Callable[[Thing,...], Any]` but that's not a valid thing to do right now.

Similarly I tried creating a TypeVar for the return value:

```
R = TypeVar("R")
F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[...,R]
def guard(func: F) -> F:
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs) -> R:
        ...
```

However this is not allowed either.

[PEP612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) offers a `ParamSpec` but I can't seem to work out how to construct one, and I'm not even sure if I did that it would help much!

Comment: Decorators aren't tiny - its an entire function call object that is created every time you use it. Would it make sense to initialize to an empty string instead of `None`? That can mean fewer special cases later.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this statically. Type-narrowing has to be done lexically, and your test and your use of `self._attrib.upper()` are in different lexical scopes.

Comment: Please share a **reproducible** example: your code, after adding a closing paren, does not give the error you show and shows (expected) `Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "upper"  [union-attr]` and (on `return inner`) `Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[Any, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]", expected "F")  [return-value]` ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=809956327b87a018e1380a1e8c1c95e0)). Both errors are pretty obvious: decorator cannot narrow anything from other scope, and `inner` is untyped and thus doesn't match decl return type.

Comment: Also I'd warn against "empty string" approach: it will hide some possible bugs, not resolve them. You should check for `self._attrib is not None` explicitly - e.g. with `assert`. It can be optimised away at runtime, if you're concerned, and helps `mypy` figure out what's happening. It would be cool to do it with decorator, but there's probably no way to do so.

Comment: No, your question mentions `Optional[Any]`, and in playground I see `Optional[str]` as part of error - another error is obvious and less important here. Also these errors have nothing to with *"the type of self [being] completely lost"* - these errors do not support this claim. The type of `self` is unchanged in `guarded_function` (`Thing`) and `Any` in `inner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can* do what you're looking for in the static typing system (whether it's a good idea in practice is based on your actual use case). Here's an example to make it work.

First, `Thing` needs to be a generic with respect to its `_attrib` type:

```py
_AttribT = TypeVar("_AttribT", str, None)

class Thing(Generic[_AttribT]):
    _attrib: _AttribT
```

Then, disallow `@guard` from accepting `self: Thing[None]`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import *


class AttribIsNoneException(Exception):
    ...


S = TypeVar("S", bound="Thing[Any]")
P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
_AttribT = TypeVar("_AttribT", str, None)


def guard(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[Thing[str], P], R]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[Thing[str], P], R]:
    def inner(self: S, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        if self._attrib is None:
            raise AttribIsNoneException()
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner
```

Instance methods of `Thing` will then be forced to be annotated with `self: Thing[str]` if decorated with `@guard`:

```py
class Thing(Generic[_AttribT]):
    _attrib: _AttribT

    @guard  # Static typing errors
    def bad_guarded_function(self) -> str:
        return self._attrib.upper()  # Static typing errors

    @guard
    def guarded_function(self: Thing[str]) -> str:
        return self._attrib.upper()
```

In practice, you will need to ensure that you're accessing `guarded_function` through a `Thing[str]` instance and not a `Thing[None]` instance. I don't really know what your code looks like, but here's one possible implementation:

```
class Thing(Generic[_AttribT]):
    _attrib: _AttribT

    def __new__(cls, attrib: _AttribT) -> Thing[_AttribT]:
        thing: Thing[_AttribT] = super().__new__(cls)
        thing._attrib = attrib
        return thing

    @guard
    def guarded_function(self: Thing[str]) -> str:
        return self._attrib.upper()


>>> string_thing = Thing("asdfjkl")
>>> string_thing.guarded_function()
>>>
>>> none_thing = Thing(None)
>>> none_thing.guarded_function()  # mypy: Invalid self argument "Thing[None]" to attribute function "guarded_function" with type "Callable[[Thing[str]], str]" [misc]
```